# {sysuserinfoorg} constant is empty

Tags: inno-setup

I am using the following but the value of `{sysuserinfoorg}` is an empty string:

```pascal
Data := 'UNINSTALL=' {sysuserinfoorg};
```

The above line returns 'UNINSTALL'.

I also tried `ExpandConstant('{sysuserinfoorg}')` with the same result.

I am using this in the `DeinitializeUninstall` procedure and sending the `Data` via HTTP post to my server which writes it to a log file. It all works but the `{sysuserinfoorg}` is empty. What I am after is some information that identifies the user and/or their organization. Inno Setup doc indicates `{sysuserinfoorg}` includes data from the registry on who the machine is registered to.

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpandConstant` is the correct way:

```pascal
Data := 'UNINSTALL=' + ExpandConstant('{sysuserinfoorg}');
```

---

The problem can be that there's actually no registered company.

Check the value of `RegisteredOrganization` value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` key.

On my machine, it's empty, hence the `{sysuserinfoorg}` is empty too.

---

The mere `{sysuserinfoorg}` is nonsense in Pascal code.

```pascal
Data := 'UNINSTALL=' {sysuserinfoorg};
```

The `{...}` is a [comment in Pascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse2.html), as you can see with enabled syntax-highlighting.

Hence the code compiles as:

```pascal
Data := 'UNINSTALL=';
```

---

You can also try to retrieve the value explicitly by reading registry:

```pascal
if RegQueryStringValue(
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_64, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion',
     'RegisteredOrganization', S) then
begin
  Log('64-bit RegisteredOrganization = ' + S)
end
  else
begin
  Log('64-bit RegisteredOrganization is not defined')
end;

if RegQueryStringValue(
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE_32, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion',
     'RegisteredOrganization', S) then
begin
  Log('32-bit RegisteredOrganization = ' + S)
end
  else
begin
  Log('32-bit RegisteredOrganization is not defined')
end;

Log('sysuserinfoname = ' + ExpandConstant('{sysuserinfoname}'));
```

Comment: after reading more of the Inno documentation, it appears that sysuserinfoorg and sysuserinfoname are values the user must provide in an optional user information wizard.  I have values in the CurrentVersion key which supports the above. Where  did you read that Inno gets the values from that key?

Comment: That's not true. Only the `{userinfo*}` constants are read from the wizard. The `{sysuserinfo*}` constants are read from the registry. It's obvious, if you check Inno Setup source code ([`ReadSysUserInfo`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/8da29b5fbbe82db8b103c6a7672b5312abc3466f/Projects/Main.pas#L1256) and [`ExpandIndividualConst`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/8da29b5fbbe82db8b103c6a7672b5312abc3466f/Projects/Main.pas#L1076) functions in `Projects/Main.pas`).

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion and every one of the values there has an entry. I tried this on two Windows 7 machines. I also tried both the ASCII and Unicode versions of Inno -latest ones installed two days ago. I also added sysinfousername and that is empty as well.

Comment: And didn't you use 32-bit version of regedit by mistake? Try also the code I've just appended to my answer.

Comment: According to MS, the 64 bit version of Regedit is the default version on 64 bit machines. I access it via Start and typing regedit.exe then run it. So no, I dont think that loads the 32 bit version. I just ran the 32 bit version by entering %systemroot%\syswow64\regedit and it does show some different values under CurrentVersion, but none are empty: registeredorganization and registereduser are both "Microsoft"

Comment: That should be good. Though no matter what I try, it works for me. Try my code. + Show us registry export from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`. Maybe there's something strange.